# Pause Vimeo video from separate a href click

Tags: vimeo, froogaloop

I am looking to be able to pause a vimeo video from a separate click event.

here is an example of what i am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/QsfF7/7/

I am trying to pause the video via the link.

Can anyone set me in the right direction pls.

---

**Update:**

Thank you. Squeeks is right, you just need to go over to github get the files, froogaloop.js

sorted

working example here

http://isimplesnippets.com/isimplesnippets/vimeo-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the froogaloop library in order to interact with the player as you're using the iframe embedding and not the older, flash specific. They have example code on [github](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript)
and documentation for [their API](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js) available.

Answer (score 3):

this jsfiddle shows playing/pausing vimeo with multiple videos using the froogaloop api. so if you start one video all other videos are stopping to play: http://jsfiddle.net/nerdess/D5fD4/3/

i think that is what you were asking for!